# [UWP][OneDrive API] SyncEngine

Tags: uwp, onedrive, office365api

I need to develop a UWP app being able to access to user's one drive (maybe silently) also able to sync all the onedrive content or a part (one directory).
 I found that this is partially doable with the Live SDK 5.6 /OneDrive sdk 2.0 or with the Office 365 API.
 Well both approach they don't have a sync engine, so by using the one or the other there will be a sync engine to wrote!
 Do you know if there is any other alternative way of doing that?
 Or about some new API coming?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You want to sync the content with an API? The OneDrive app/service should do that and the user should be in control.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [delta functionality](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm) that our [new api](https://dev.onedrive.com) has - it should let you keep your UWP app in sync with the cloud state. You may also want to check out the [SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) as well to make integration easier. It contains some samples that should show how auth would work etc.

Comment: This is Gian, nice to meet you. I've already checked that samples and I wasn't able to find out how to keep in sync the app and the cloud. What I mean is how to manage conflicts and so on. An async method like SyncFolders(folderOne, folderTwo, params[]) that will fire an event when finished :D Can you point me to that code?

Thank you -g

Comment: I don't believe there's any boiler plate code to resolve conflicts as it's pretty application dependent (E.g. a file sync would behave differently to an app that wants to sync settings - one has context of the content of the files and knows how to merge, the other doesn't).